# Preprocessing form data before saving to the database

Tags: joomla-3.x, database, form, array

I have a series of checkboxes on my form that together form an array when POST'ed. I want to save this data as a string instead (e.g., "##,##,##") before committing to the database.

Here's what I have in the \models\componentname.php:

```
public function save($data)
{
    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $filter  = JFilterInput::getInstance();

    if(isset($data['dancer_id'])) {     
        $data['dancer_id'] = implode(",", $data['dancer_id']);
    }

    if (parent::save($data))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And here is the custom field type I've created (\models\fields\fieldname.php):

```
<div class="dancer"><input id="dancer_id" type="checkbox" name="dancer_id[]" value="XXX" />XXX</div>
```

All other fields in the form save except for this one. Any thoughts? Also I'm not sure how the $data is being passed to the save() function ... maybe I've missed a call somewhere? To get this far, I followed the HelloWorld MVC component tutorial on the Joomla site and the response in [this related thread](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9366/pre-processing-form-data-before-display-save-whats-the-standard-approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out with the help of someone on the Joomla DEV Google Groups ([details](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/joomla-dev-general/EhH0qoRk1uw/ajTtDKYXBwAJ)): I did not have my custom field dancer_id added to the jform array like so:

```
<input id="dancer_id" type="checkbox" name="jform[dancer_id][]" value="2261" checked>
```

Once I did so, it all worked. Details linked above.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried retrieving the form input directly without using JFilterInput?

Try this:

replace:

```
$filter  = JFilterInput::getInstance();
```

with:

```
$dancers = $input->get('dancer','','array');
```

you can then do

```
$data['dancer_id'] = implode(",", $dancers);
```

From there you can finish up with your save methods

Comment: Turns out I didn't have my custom field added to the jform array ... I've edited my original question with my solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries, from the field name I was unaware you were using jform or I'd have pointed that out lol.